# Simulating field collapsing/grouping by field in Elastic Search

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search, elasticsearch

Elastic Search does not currently (as of 0.18.4) support field collapsing. Is there a good way to simulate this, as to avoid *N* search queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the answer you're looking for but: As far as I know, and according to [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256) ticket, the only real workaround is to select a larger result set and group on the client side.

Comment: bad idea ... as you don't know what are the actual count of rows

Comment: not really a bad idea. Just try it and see that its fast even for even >1000 docs (if not too big docs)

Comment: @Karussell this is technically a hack. for small document sets, sure, it might be acceptable. as your index increases, this approach's feasibility decreases.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your use case is you might find parent/child support or nested types useful instead.

You can find more about parent/child support here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/553
(and then in corresponding query/filter doc pages)

As for nested types, check here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type.html