# Variation in ElasticSearch Results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to introduce variation in ElasticSearch results. Something similar to how Google restricts results on domain name, e.g. it would usually show max 1 or 2 results from any particular domain.

e.g. if we're searching on blog comments, only show 2 comments for any particular blog post.

I don't think it can be done with facets, because we're constraining on a field that has thousands of possible values. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you're talking about grouping. There's an open [issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256) about it. You can also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304418/simulating-field-collapsing-grouping-by-field-in-elastic-search) other question to see if you can work around it in your case.

There is a [fork](https://github.com/martijnvg/elasticsearch-with-local-grouping) which provides local grouping but it works only locally. That would force you to use only one shard, which doesn't make a lot of sense with elasticsearch.

Given the interest around elasticsearch and the grouping feature itself, as well as the fact that there's now a [company](http://www.elasticsearch.com/) behind the project, I guess the issue will be closed soon. At least that's what I hope!

Comment: Thanks, not an ideal situation, but this helps me understand how the requirement fits into the overall landscape.